# amalgamation morphing effects

Tags: animation, video

Doesn't mean to ripped off. I know how to create morphing between images but does anyone know how to make the animated wavy effects showcase [here](http://vimeo.com/32351411)?

Comment: More answers to same question here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15512/how-to-create-the-effect-in-this-animated-gif-of-morphing-faces

Answer (score 2):

**Some guesses**

To me, it looks like they've prepared the photos so the eyes, mouth and head shapes overlay as closely as possible. The animation looks like two main aspects are changing.

1. Alpha channel animation
2. They're using [2D morphing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphing)

The alpha channel looks to have a soft diagonal pattern though it that's scrolling from top to bottom. This is what's giving it the "wavy" effect, because the different faces have different width features, like hair.

The morphing is a little harder to pin down. I'm not sure if there's anything special going on there.

And I also don't know how the triangles that you can see at some points relate. They seem to be strictly for the morphing. It's been a while since I've done any work with morphing, but there used to be some good software around for it. The name escapes me though.

Edit: The author says this in the comments.

> Hi, this is a morphing + a set mask filters.

Doesn't give much away, but suggests I may have been on the right path?

Comment: Thanks Marc. I red the comments too. Can't figure out what "a set mask filters" means tho.

Comment: Mask = alpha channel. So I think they're talking about animating the mask.

Comment: 2 animation at the same time?