# How to create the effect in this animated GIF of morphing faces?

Tags: effects, gif

I saw an [amazing animated gif](http://www.quilime.com/aggregate/agg/Internetism2_Micael_Reynaud.gif)

And I thought I should give it a go.

I tried laying out several friends' pictures in movie maker and power director and though I sort of have a video where it is animated up to an extent, it is not as fluid, it feels more like a slideshow no matter how much I tweak the time/tween.

I thought, may be I need to fine control it and opened up Photoshop and added layer mask to go from image to image...though this is a lot better, I still don't have this fluidity.

I am not sure this is the right place to ask this question, but do any of you know how this method can be achieved? I think it's a great pic!

Comment: That is very similar to this, if not the same: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lugDrGlQTQ

Answer (score 7):

This has very little to do with GIFs.

Firstly you need to create the **face-morph effect**. There are apps that do it for you but it isn't a one-click process.

Secondly ther is a **transition effect** to blend between stages. It includes tiles, waves and a gradient mask.

Either way, this video (which it was at one point) isn't an easy process if video editing is not your field.

Final step, **converting to gif**: This can be done by most professional video editing programs, but you can also find online converters. Google will help with that.

Comment: I think that there is *possibly* a flag-wave loop being used as for lighting modulation. The tiles seem fairly uniform, probably a static filter but give the impression of motion due to the shoulders and background from individual portraits. The two (one?) basic effects are applied with a central gradient mask such that the effects are more pronounced at the edges of the frame and the center is more purely the morphed frames.

Comment: Great addition on how to execute those details. I totally missed the gradient mask.

Answer (score 1):

After Effects is the best program for this. There is also a wave effect effecting the opacity of the tiles which cant easily be replicated in PS.

GIF is just a format to export to after it is created, it could just as easily be an .MP4, .MOV or .AVI.